# Having trouble creating an articulated arm in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, jogl

I am attempting to create an articulated arm in OpenGL (JAVA). I have started by creating a drawTriangle method, which draws 3 triangles onto the canvas, all slightly overlapping each other. I am now attempting to code a drawArm method, which starts by calling the drawTriangle method, and then using glPushMatrix, glPopMatrix, glTranslate, and glRotate, will be able to rotate the arm at specific points (where the triangles overlap).

Here is my drawTriangle method:

```
public void drawTriangle(GL gl, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, 
        int x3, int y3) {

    gl.glTranslatef(-2.0f, -1.5f, -6.0f);

    // Drawing first red triangle
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl.glColor3f(1f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1f, 1f, 0.0f);    // Bottom Left
    gl.glVertex3f(1f, 1.2f, 0.0f);     // Top left
    gl.glVertex3f(2f, 1.1f, 0.0f);      // Pointy bit
    gl.glEnd();   
    gl.glTranslatef(0.9f, 0f, 0f);

    // Drawing first red triangle
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl.glColor3f(0f, 1f, 0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1f, 1f, 0.0f);    // Bottom Left
    gl.glVertex3f(1f, 1.2f, 0.0f);     // Top left
    gl.glVertex3f(2f, 1.1f, 0.0f);      // Pointy bit
    gl.glEnd();   
    gl.glTranslatef(0.9f, 0f, 0f);

    // Drawing first red triangle
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl.glColor3f(0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1f, 1f, 0.0f);    // Bottom Left
    gl.glVertex3f(1f, 1.2f, 0.0f);     // Top left
    gl.glVertex3f(2f, 1.1f, 0.0f);      // Pointy bit
    gl.glEnd();   
    gl.glTranslatef(0.9f, 0f, 0f);
}
```

And here is my starting attempt at my drawArm method:

```
public void drawArm(GL gl, float offset, float angle1, float angle2) {

    // Call drawTriangle method
    drawTriangle(gl,0,0,0,5,10,7);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(-2.0f,-1.5f,-6.0f);  // Translates to origin of first triangle
    gl.glRotatef(offset, angle1, angle2, offset);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    gl.glEnd();   
}
```

I will then call the drawArm method from inside my display() method, where offset is the length of each arm, angle 1 changes the rotation between triangle 1 and 2, and angle 2 changes the rotation between triangle 2 and 3.

Any help with writing the drawArm method?

Comment: Please switch to JOGL 2 first. JOGL 1 maintenance was stopped in 2010. There should be a call to glBegin per call to glEnd which isn't the case in your code. Just as a reminder, we're here to help you, not to do your homework or assignment.

Comment: Look at this example in C++ (robotarm.cpp): http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/openglexamples/ It should be straightforward to port into Java.